# Set tooltip on click event on the grid cell

Tags: extjs, grid, tooltip, cell

I'm trying to show a tooltip when the user clicks on a grid cell. When I click on a cell, the tooltip appears. The problem is, after the click, it keeps popping up whenever I move the mouse over any other cell. I'm using Ext JS 4.2.1. Let down the code as I am treating the CellClick event in the controller and the way I am creating the tooltip.

```
onCellClick: function (view, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts) {
var store = Ext.getStore('pontoeletronico');        
if (view.tip) {
    view.tip.destroy();                        
    view.tip = null;            
}        
if(cellIndex > 0 && cellIndex < 5) {
    view.tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
        autoShow: false,
        showDelay: 0,                                    
        stateful: false,
        target: view.el,
        width: 100,
        title: 'Horário original',
        delegate: view.cellSelector,
        trackMouse: false,
        autoHide: true,
        listeners: {
            beforeshow: function (tooltip, eOpts) {
                var ponto = store.findRecord('id', record.get('idPonto'));
                var horario;
                if (cellIndex == 1) {
                    horario = ponto.get('entrada01');                        
                } else if (cellIndex = 2) {
                    horario = ponto.get('saida01');                        
                } else if (cellIndex == 3) {
                    horario = ponto.get('entrada02');                        
                } else if (cellIndex == 4) {
                    horario = ponto.get('saida02');                        
                }
                horario = horario != null ? Ext.Date.format(horario, 'H:i:s') : "--:--:--";                    
                //tooltip.update(horario);
                tooltip.html = horario;                    

            }                
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem, but leave open in case someone give a better solution.

Well, for the tooltip only appear when I clicked and vanish when I move the mouse, I added an event in the controller called itemmouseleave. Thus, when the item under which the mouse is change I destroy the tooltip added to that view. The final code was as follows:

```
onItemMouseLeave: function (view, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
    if (view.tip) {
        view.tip.destroy();
    }  
},

onCellClick: function (view, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts) {
    var store = Ext.getStore('pontoeletronico');        
    if (view.tip) {
        view.tip.destroy();                        
        view.tip = null;            
    }        
    if(cellIndex > 0 && cellIndex < 5) {            
        view.tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
            itemId: 'tooltip-horario',
            autoShow: false,
            showDelay: 0,                                    
            stateful: false,
            target: view.el,
            width: 100,
            title: 'Horário original',
            delegate: view.cellSelector,
            trackMouse: false,
            autoHide: true
        });
        var ponto = store.findRecord('id', record.get('idPonto'));
        var horario;
        if (cellIndex == 1) {
            horario = ponto.get('entrada01');                        
        } else if (cellIndex = 2) {
            horario = ponto.get('saida01');                        
        } else if (cellIndex == 3) {
            horario = ponto.get('entrada02');                        
        } else if (cellIndex == 4) {
            horario = ponto.get('saida02');                        
        }
        horario = horario != null ? Ext.Date.format(horario, 'H:i:s') : "--:--:--";                    
        view.tip.update(horario);                                     
    }                              
}
```